# Port 5588 Connection Refused

Tags: port

Before I make this, please note that I have searched and found no answer to why this is happening. So do not mark this as a duplicate as that's invalid.

For some reason when I go to http://canyouseeme.org it says for port 5588 that the connection was refused, but yet simple ports like 80, 443, etc all can be seen.

I have them portforwarded through the firewall perfectly on my VPS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about TCP or UDP port 5588? Is the server which uses port 5588 running? Is it configured to listen on the correct interface?

Comment: UDP & TCP,  and no because I can't get it running DUE to the port is being blocked.

Comment: If a program isn’t listening it will of course result in “Connection refused”.

Comment: That can't be true though, when I was into a different game the port required 43594 to be forwarded and it said it can see the open port without the program listening/running.

Comment: I'm running MySQL service right now and it even says 3306 is refused, even though it's open.

Answer (score 1):

All port forwarding does is send any packets that arrive on the outside interface of your router on a specific port to a device on the inside of your router.  If that device is not set up to respond to the incoming packets, then if the connection is TCP it will either issue a "connection refused" packet (the packet is actually a TCP RST packet), or ignore it if there is a firewall in place.  If it is UDP, then the packet will be ignored.

From the perspective of something external to your network, a port that is forwarded to a device that isn't listening for it may look identical to one that is not port forwarded at all.

If you have set up your router correctly and want to test that the port forward is functioning, start the service that should accept the incoming connections.  A test without this running will not reveal anything useful.